# atof() in K&R book 4.2

Tags: c, atof

I'm exercising `atof()` which is provided in K&R book *4.2*. However, when I compile the following code, I get

```
1952.690000
```

instead of

```
1237.88
```

I tried, but still don't know where's wrong. Maybe there is a problem with type conversions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

double atof(char s[]) {
  int i, sign;
  double n, power;

  for (i = 0; isspace(s[i]); ++i)
    ;

  sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1 : 1;
  if (s[i] == '-' || s[i] == '+')
    ++i;

  for (n = 0.0; isdigit(s[i]); ++i)
    n += n * 10.0 + s[i] - '0';

  if (s[i] == '.')
    ++i;
  for (power = 1.0; isdigit(s[i]); ++i) {
    n += n * 10.0 + s[i] - '0';
    power *= 10.0;
  }

  return sign * n / power;
}

int main() {
  char s[] = "1237.88";

  printf("%lf", atof(s));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think you're doing with `n+=n*10.0+s[i]-'0';`?

Comment: "// Why there is no need to set sign as a double?" ?????

Comment: `+=` ---> `=`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @Stargateur  Irrelevant to this question. I have deteled it.

Comment: Making your own function called `atof` is undefined behaviour -- it'd be better to use your own name such as `my_atof`. Also `printf("%lf"` did not exist in K&R's time,  if you are using an old compiler it'd be better to use `"%f"` as the fomrat string

Comment: @M.M Valuable teaching. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're not understanding the combined assignment operator well.

Here's the error in your code:

```
n+=n*10.0+s[i]-'0';
 ^^
```

Note it's `+=`, add-and-assign. Based on the code I deduce that it's not what you intended to do. You should instead change it to a regular assignment operator:

```
n = n*10.0+s[i]-'0';
  ^
```

And the result is correct.

For the other question in the comments in your code:

> ```
> // Why there is no need to set sign as a double?
> ```

You can of course do it and you won't observe any difference in the results, so there is no **need** to do it (not *you can't do it*). It simply adds nothing to the code.

Comment: My god, it's due to my carelessness. Thanks for your help!